# Github page showing desktop view on mobile

Tags: css, github, responsive-design

https://faultde.github.io/rps-v1/

When I scale the window on a computer,the page resizes, but when I load it on my phone it doesn't scale. Can't seem to find the problem in my CSS.

Comment: You have missed the meta tag. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24911272/3008050

Answer (score 0):

in body css you have given margin:30px and width 100% remove both